# Customize button in android studio

Tags: android, xml, generics, button, android-drawable

I try to create custom button in android studio.

I already create a xml file in drawable folder with name bg.xml and I wrote  this code in    bg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item>

     <shape android:shape="rectangle">

         <stroke android:color="#00E5FF"

             android:width="5dp"/>

     </shape>

 </item>
```

and in activity_main.xml file  I wrote this code

Still the design is no reflect in button

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

 android:layout_width="match_parent"

 android:layout_height="match_parent"

 tools:context=".MainActivity"

 android:background="@drawable/bg"

 android:gravity="center">

 <Button

     android:layout_width="wrap_content"

     android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     android:text="Custom Button"

     android:background="@drawable/bg"

     />
```

I try to create custom button in android studio

Answer (score 0):

the code you posted at a first glance seems correct. Please check if you have a custom theme applied to the activity since it can override your style for the button. Try also rebuilding the project going in `Build -> Clean Project` and then `Build -> Rebuild project`.
Let me know if my suggestions helped.